# How to check for a concrete file-extension of an unsaved file with office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint, office-js

How can I check the concrete filetype / fileextension of an unsaved file wihtin Word / Powerpoint while using the Javascript API (Office.js, version 1.1).

I know, how I could get the URL (with extension) of a saved file:

```
Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(...);
```

But for a not saved file, the returned url is empty.

Comment: The URL would point to a file, no?  Until the presentation is saved, there IS no file, so I don't see how there would be a URL other than an empty one.  And until the file is saved, there's no file type either.

Comment: But it is possible to get the unsaved filecontent via API. The only thing I would need to know is would be the filetype.

Also, there are issures with the file-URL. (Open Word, show taskpane-app, save as *odt, call the api to get the URL (filename + ext) call the api to get the content -> file name "file.odt", but content is still docx.

An API to get the appication HOST (Word oder Powerpoint) would be sufficient.

Comment: There can be no file type until there's a file.  The unsaved application content might be saved in any of half a dozen different file types, if not more.

Comment: Thats true, BUT: Word will only upload *.docx (even, If I saved the file as *.odt) via office.js API. The question is: How will I find out, it is Word?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?  If Word will only upload a DOCX using the API, the files uploaded using the API will be DOCX, no?

Comment: But the same application is running within all Office-Hosts. SO I don't know if if it is *docx or *pptx

Comment: I'm completely lost here, so I'm going to bow out rather than confuse things further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up, creating multiple manifest.xml and creating a url-parameter for the correct extension.

Now I was able to separate the different file-types.

Instead of an `office.manifest.xml` I made a `word.manifest.xml` an excel.manifest.xml and a `powerpoint.manifest.xml`

They are nearly identical:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Document"/>
</Capabilities>
<DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://myserver.com/myapp.html?filetype=docx"/>
</DefaultSettings>
```

They differ only in the capability and the filetype parameter.

**Update:**

There is also a Query-Parameter from Office itself `_host_Info`, this parameter holds the needed information, but it is not documented. I am not sure if it supposed to be part of the API.

Comment: we are evaluating adding an API to detect host ("Excel, Word, Outlook, etc) & platform (Desktop, Mac, Web, etc) info. To make sure we're taking it into account, am I correct to understand that you only needed the host in this particular case, and not the platform?  Can you imagine a real-world scenario where you *would* need the platform as well (I can think of some, but I want to gauge how likely folks are actually to use it in the real-world).  Thanks!

Comment: My scenario is a document-management-system. We are embedding th same application into all three hosts (for outlook, we are following a different approach). We want to offer a way to store the open file into our system. Therefor I would need the concrete filetype. But the way to get the filetype buggy for not safed files or files, that are a stored a *.odf not *.doxc. (in Word 2013 you will get file.odf, but the content is docx. In Office 2016, I get file.odf with odf-content.) I cannot store the file to my server, because of the wrong extension. I needed to know, what extension to add.

Comment: But to answer your question: Right now, I would not neet to know neither to platform nor the host, if the API would work with feature-detection. What I really would need would be a integration into the host-UI, like contextmenu or or ribbons (to integrate my actions) or trigger if the file is saved, to update the file within my backend. Feel free to contact me for more information about my application or needed APIs.